# difference between hosted/development mode and web mode in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and I have heard of people using the terms hosted/development mode and web mode.
Can somebody please explain these?

Comment: How about reading the docs? https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try quickly,

In eclipse, you implement java code. While you develop, you can run your applications in developement mode. Runnig like this, gwt client stuff is ran by eclipse plugins as java code.
Allowing debug, tracing in console.

When you run it in a web mode, on a extrenal server, you have to export/deploy war files.
Before this, you ran the gwt compiler which converts java code to many flavours of javascript matching exactly each browser capabilities.

These are called 'permutations' when you do "google>compile gwt"

The good things in dev mode are: tracing, realtime debugging, but is a bit slow.

The good things in web mode are: speed, no matter of client browser.

Hope this helps, others are welcome to extend this reply.

Comment: so it means that in dev mode, no javascript is generated and simply the java code runs?

Comment: I think so. but it's not a problem!